# Lie group embeddings $SU(5) \supset SU(3) \times SU(2) \times U(1)?$

Tags: group-theory, differential-geometry, manifolds, lie-groups, lie-algebras

Does the special unitary Lie group $SU(5)$ contains $SU(3) \times SU(2) \times U(1)$ as a subgroup?

Can one show which of the following embeddings are possible rigorously:
$$SU(5) \supset SU(3) \times SU(2) \times U(1)?$$
$$SU(5) \supset \frac{SU(3) \times SU(2) \times U(1)}{\mathbb{Z}_2}?$$
$$SU(5) \supset \frac{SU(3) \times SU(2) \times U(1)}{\mathbb{Z}_3}?$$
$$SU(5) \supset \frac{SU(3) \times SU(2) \times U(1)}{\mathbb{Z}_3 \times \mathbb{Z}_2}?$$

Here $\mathbb{Z}_n$ means the cyclic group of order $n$.

it looks to me that the first one is impossible, can we prove it is a no go?

(p.s. $SO(10)$ and $SU(5)$ are different groups - how can the two questions be duplicate to each other, without knowing the way of embedding?)

Comment: See also [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2961471/lie-group-embeddings-so10-supset-su3-times-su2-times-u1).

Comment: (p.s. SO(10) and SU(5) are different groups - how can the two questions be duplicate to each other, without knowing the way of embedding?)