# Lie group embeddings $SO(10) \supset SU(3) \times SU(2) \times U(1)?$

Tags: group-theory, differential-geometry, lie-groups, lie-algebras, smooth-manifolds

Let $G$ be $SO(10)$ or $Spin(10)$.

Does either of them $G=SO(10)$ or $G=Spin(10)$ contain  $SU(3) \times SU(2) \times U(1)$ as a subgroup?

Can one show which of the following embeddings are possible rigorously:
$$G\supset SU(3) \times SU(2) \times U(1)?$$
$$G \supset \frac{SU(3) \times SU(2) \times U(1)}{\mathbb{Z}_2}?$$
$$G \supset \frac{SU(3) \times SU(2) \times U(1)}{\mathbb{Z}_3}?$$
$$G \supset \frac{SU(3) \times SU(2) \times U(1)}{\mathbb{Z}_3 \times \mathbb{Z}_2}?$$

Here $\mathbb{Z}_n$ means the cyclic group of order $n$.

it looks to me that the first one is impossible, can we prove it is a no go? for $G=SO(10)$ or $G=Spin(10)$?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think there is an embedding of $SU(3)\times SU(2)\times U(1)$ into $SO(10)$, but I am not sure whether this is what you want. You simply view $\mathbb C^5$ as $\mathbb R^{10}$ and recall that the standard inner product on $\mathbb R^{10}$ is the real part of the standard Hermitian inner product on  $\mathbb C^5$. Splitting $\mathbb C^5=\mathbb C^3\times\mathbb C^2$ you can than define a representation of $SU(3)\times SU(2)\times U(1)$ by $(A,B,\lambda)\cdot (z,w):=(\lambda Az,\lambda Bw)$. Each of theses maps is visibly unitary and thus orthogonal so you obtain a homomorphims to $O(10)$, which has values in $SO(10)$ since $SU(3)\times SU(2)\times U(1)$ is connected. Thus one only has to check injectivity. But if you assume that $(\lambda Az,\lambda Bw)=(z,w)$ for all $z$ and $w$, then looking at the second component, you must have $(B.\lambda)=(\mathbb I,1)$ or $(-\mathbb I,-1)$. But since minus the identity is not contained in $SU(3)$, you conclude that only the identity element of $SU(3)\times SU(2)\times U(1)$ acts as the identity on $\mathbb C^5$.

**Edit** (addressing your quesiont about SU(5)): As stated above, the homomorphism has values $U(5)\subset SO(10)$. The determinant of the action of $(A,B,\lambda)$ by construction is $\lambda^5\det(A)\det(B)=\lambda^5$. Guided by this, there is an obvious modification which does have values in $SU(5)$, namely $(A,B,\lambda)\cdot (z,w):=(\bar\lambda^2Az,\lambda^3Bz)$, or in matrix language, sending $(A,B,\lambda)$ to the block matrix $\begin{pmatrix} \bar\lambda^2A & 0 \\ 0 &  \lambda^3B\end{pmatrix}$. Now this has values in $SU(5)$, but it is not injective any more. I haven't checked very carefully, but I think the kernel should be $\mathbb Z_3\times\mathbb Z_2$ with generators $(\zeta^2 \mathbb I,\mathbb I,\zeta)$ for $\zeta$ a third root of unity and $(\mathbb I,-\mathbb I,-1)$. I don't know whether one can do better.

Comment: are you sure we do not need to mod any normal subgroup $\mathbb{Z}_n$ in(3)×(2)×(1) to be embedded to SO(10)?

Comment: p.s. I had voted up, but am not sure the answer

Comment: This should be exactly the last part of the answer: We must have $(A,B,\lambda)$ acts as the identity on $\mathbb C^5$ if and only if $\lambda A$ and  $\lambda B$ both are the identiy matrix. But since $\det)B=1$, $\lambda B=\mathbb I$ implies $\lambda^2=1$ so $\lambda=\pm 1$. But $\lambda=-1$ is not possible, since then $\lambda A=\mathbb I$ would say that $A=-\mathbb I$, but this has determinant $-1$.

Comment: How about this? https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2961466/141334

Comment: I have edited the answer to address this.

Comment: accepted, this is consistent with what I understand too! thanks

Comment: do you happen can comment this as well, math.stackexchange.com/questions/3607058, I believe some version is true

Comment: May I make sure your notation: (i)  $(A,B,\lambda)\in ℂ^3 $ and $(z,w)\in ℂ^2 $?

Comment: (ii) $(A,B,\lambda)\in SU(3) \times U(1) $ and  $(z,w)\in SU(2) \times U(1) $? or
$(A,B,\lambda)\in (SU(3) \times U(1))/ℤ_3=U(3) $ and  $(z,w)\in (SU(2) \times U(1) )/ℤ_2=U(2)$?

Comment: The notation is $A\in SU(3)$, $B\in SU(2)$, $\lambda\in U(1)$. In the second part, this is enough, since you can just use the presentation as block matrices. This is possbile in the real case, too, but it needs systematically expressing complex matrices as real matrices. To avoid this, I have just written how the elements act on a vector in $\mathbb C^5$. Two write this out, the vector is split as $(z,w)$ with $z\in\mathbb C^3$ and $w\in\mathbb C^2$.

Comment: In both cases, you obtain a homomorphism $SU(3)\times SU(2)\times U(1)\to G$, where $G$ is $SO(10)$ or $U(5)$ in the first case and $SU(5)$ in the second case. If such a homomoephism is injective, it is the embedding of a subgroup, if not, you have to factorize by the kernel of the homomorphism in order to get the group that is embedde.

Comment: hi guys - could you perhaps help math.stackexchange.com/q/4217648/955245 ?

Comment: also  math.stackexchange.com/q/4217668/955245

Comment: @AndreasCap Your description of the kernel is in fact correct, in case anyone is wondering.